# Django Error - Reverse for 'new_bid' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm somewhat new to Django and creating a way for users to 'bid' on items, similar to ebay. I am getting the error: Reverse for 'new_bid' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['new_bid/(?P[0-9]+)$']

The traceback is available for one day on this site (I was having trouble copy and pasting it here)
https://dpaste.com/EYMGRBCEN

I know I have some things mixed up, specifically the end of views.py in the return render request but I'm not sure what I need to have there.
I know in the html {% url 'new_bid' i.id %} is also not correct, but I'm struggling to figure out what should be here as well. Any help is appreciated as I'd like to learn more.

views.py

```
def new_bid(request, listingid):
    current_bid = Listings.objects.get(id=listingid)
    current_bid = current_bid.starting_bid
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_bid = int(request.POST.get("bid"))
        if user_bid > current_bid:
            listing_items = Listings.objects.get(id=listingid)
            listing_items.starting_bid = user_bid
            listing_items.save()
            try:
                if Bid.objects.filter(id=listingid):
                    bidrow = Bid.objects.filter(id=listingid)
                    bidrow.delete()
                bidtable = Bid()
                bidtable.user = request.user.username
                bidtable.title = listing_items.title
                bidtable.listingid = listingid
                bidtable.bid = user_bid
                bidtable.save()

            except:
                bidtable = Bid()
                bidtable.user = request.user.username
                bidtable.title = listing_items.title
                bidtable.listingid = listingid
                bidtable.bid = user_bid
                bidtable.save()

            Bid.objects.filter(id=listingid)
            return render(request, "auctions/listing.html", {
                "i": "id"
            })
        else:
            response = redirect('listingpage', id=listingid)
            response.set_cookie('error', 'Bid should be greater than current price', max_age=3)
            return response
    else:
        return redirect('index')
```

The urls in urls.py

```
    path("listings/<int:id>", views.listingpage, name="listingpage"),

    path("new_bid/<int:listingid>", views.new_bid, name="new_bid"),
```

Relevant html:

```
        <p class="lead" align="justify"><strong>Place your Bid : </strong></p>
        <form action="{% url 'new_bid' i.id %}" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="newbid" placeholder="Your Bid">


  
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you post the full error stack trace? Maybe you have problem in a different template

Comment: What id `i.id` here? It seems `i.id` returning an empty/None value

Comment: @LinhNguyen https://dpaste.com/EYMGRBCEN - here is the traceback. I know it says the issue is in my layout html file, but I didn't think it was really there, because I've seen this same error a while ago for a different project and it said the issue was in layout but it ended up not being the case. Anyway, I made sure my user really was signed in. And my user is signed in. So I'm not actually sure why it's throwing that error.